# Error when trying to install react-redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-redux, react-redux-form

My NPM cannot install **react-redux-form** for my project.
I need assistance, please.

C:\Users\folder>npm install react-redux-form@latest --save
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: confusion@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-redux-form@1.16.14
npm ERR! node_modules/react-redux-form
npm ERR!   react-redux-form@"1.16.14" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-03-01T03_50_51_548Z-debug.log


**After compilation**

Failed to compile
./src/components/ContactComponent.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-redux-form' in 'C:\Users\dir\src\components'
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

**My Jason file**

```
  "name": "james-react-website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-social": "^5.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.1.2",
    "react-popper": "^0.9.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "reactstrap": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.68.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^8.3.8",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest Node v15 and npm v7 releases, `npm install redux-form` will fail.

I believe this is due to some changes in NPM. Can read more about it [here](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/626173315965468672/npm-v7-series-beta-release-and-semver-majory).

If you're using NPM, run this command instead:

```
npm install redux-form --legacy-peer-deps
```

Hope this solves your issue!

Comment: Please can you send the link again?